# Unicity of Rankin-Selberg 'factors'

Tags: number-theory, l-functions

Suppose $H$ is an automorphic L-function obtained by applying the Rankin-Selberg convolution to two automorphic L-functions $F$ and $G$ each of them being different from the Riemann Zeta function. Is the set $\{F,G\}$ entirely determined by $H$?

Comment: on the automorphic side, or on the Dirichlet series / Selberg class side ? (it is different, even if as far as I understand it, the different conjectures relating the two are taken for granted) and did you look at [Kaczorowski's papers](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.4734v1.pdf) working in the extended Selberg class (meromorphic + functional equation, but no need for an Euler product)

Comment: I don't feel comfortable with the extended Selberg class, to me it doesn't make sense to drop the Euler product requirement. By the way, I'm interested in the automorphic side, since the unique factorization has been proven in that case, so maybe the question is easier to tackle.